# Bind custom attribute value to route constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

How do I bind a custom attribute value to a route?

What I want:

```csharp
[ApiController]
[CustomAttribute("value")]
[Route("{customAttributeValue}/[controller")]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    //...
}
```

Then my route should appear like this.
[image]

I saw that for the first time when versioning apis

```csharp
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("2")] 
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    //...
}
```

So in swagger, this example controller looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by defining that custom attribute, which accepts the `string` value that must be part of the route.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class CustomValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CustomValueAttribute(string value)
        => Value = value;

    public string Value { get; }
}
```

Set up an [`IActionModelConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.iactionmodelconvention) to apply that attribute value to the route of the controller being executed.  Here you decide upon the name you want to apply as a placeholder in the route definition; the below example uses `customValue`.

```
public sealed class CustomValueRoutingConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        var value = action.Controller.ControllerType.GetCustomAttribute<CustomValueAttribute>()?.Value;
        if (value is not null)
        {
            action.RouteValues.Add("customValue", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Next step is to hook the above convention to the [`MvcOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.conventions).
You can do that when calling `AddControllers`.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    mvcOptions => mvcOptions.Conventions.Add(new CustomValueRoutingConvention())
);
```

Finally, that `CustomValueAttribute`and route placeholder get applied to the controller.  Notice the `[customValue]` placeholder in the route.

```
[ApiController]
[CustomValue("value")]
[Route("[customValue]/[controller]")]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
```

---

A view from Swagger

[image]

Comment: thaanks a lot man. This was exactaly what I've being looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom route attribute to solve this.

Example code:

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{

public class MyCustomValueAttribute : RouteAttribute
{

    public MyCustomValueAttribute(string route, string prefixRoute, int prefixRouteCustomValue) : base($"{prefixRoute}/{prefixRouteCustomValue}/{route}")
    {


    }
}


[ApiController]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    
    [HttpGet]
    [MyCustomValue("[controller]", "value", 20)]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

}

Outputs:
[image]

Comment: Hi Geoffrey. Thanks for your answer. Yes this way could work, but i want it to work like api versioning does. Get the api versioning value and substitute in custom route constraint apiVersion

Comment: Hi Vinicius, sorry this wasn't exactly what you were looking for. 

If no one is able to help you I would recommend looking at the source code of the ApiVersion attribute. 


[AddApiVersioning Attribute source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/ms/src/Common/ApiVersionAttribute.cs) and here is the

[addApiVersioning in startup.cs source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/88cb5468fc64ef6c1d5497047753955d58d293f3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/IServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L144)